# Session_Start or PHP Requests Doesn't Work

Tags: php

Wit the code below I'm always automatically logged out from my system.. If I remove all classes includes session works very well..

I'm not sure where the problem is ..... session_start or bad PHP requests ?? Any suggestion? Thanks!

Update:
Ah... I just remove updateUserSession from my code and works fine now

Comment: Use `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at the top (_before_ `session_start()`). Having `display_errors 0` commented out does not imply it's enabled. Always do this when developing and testing code.  You said the session works when all class includes are commented out. Comment them individually to find which single one has the effect of breaking your session, then post its contents. Remove the whitespace before `<?php` at the top, as any output (whitespace included) before `session_start()` or `header()` will break it.

Comment: Have you made sure you started the session on the page that actually sets the sessions? Otherwise it won't transfer through requests.

Answer (score 0):

1. Be sure that `$_SESSION['user_name']` and `$_SESSION['user_id']` contain valid values.
2. I think this part of code is wrong: `if($_SESSION['user_id']==1)` and must be `if(!empty($_SESSION['user_id']))`

About the second point, your current code is verifying that user_id is 1, instead with my replacement PHP verifies that `$_SESSION['user_id']` is **NOT** empty.